# C Program to calculate difference of n natural numbers using recursion and recursion is must to use

Tags: c

I wrote the code but I am getting the wrong output. Say for example when I enter 5 the output I am getting is 3 instead it should be -5. Please point out my mistakes and provide me some solutions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int difference(int a);

int difference(int a)

{
    if (a != 0)
    {

        return (a - difference(a - 1));
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int main()

{
    int n;

    printf("Enter number until which you want difference of:\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("The difference of numbers is %d", difference(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean -5 instead of 5?

Comment: "difference of numbers X to Y" ehhh, X - Y?

Comment: You're trying to get a difference of two numbers but your function only takes one input? Could you please add more clarity

Comment: no I am not trying to get negative number. I just want correct output

Comment: Then you will need to explain what "difference of n natural numbers" means and why you think the answer should be -5.

Comment: Why don't just use X - Y?

Comment: You definitely need to see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Prior to that, however, please specify in arithmetic terms what your program is _supposed_ to do.

Comment: my program is supposed should run like this. If I input 5, the program should run like this 5-4-3-2-1-0 and the output I should get is -5.

Comment: As the answer by Joop Eggen shows, you get perfectly correct output from this code. Possibly you used a wrong code?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (edit the question, though). Is recursion mandatory?

Comment: I hope I clarified your doubts and recursion is mandatory

Comment: It's quite hard to achieve what you describe with recursion. But you can rework the maths as `5-(4+3+2+1+0)` and then the parenthesised part is pretty simply recursive.

Comment: thanks this information is very helpful

Comment: If you are not allowed to eveluate the result with a single call, a pure recursive implementation is slightly different from your attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/E98T155zE

Comment: @Bob__ A shortened version of the compact formula is `i*(3 - i)/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this seems home work, just the error cause:

```
d 5 = [a] 5 - d 4 = [k] 5 - 2 = 3
d 4 = [b] 4 - d 3 = [j] 4 - 2 
d 3 = [c] 3 - d 2 = [i] 3 - 1
d 2 = [d] 2 - d 1 = [h] 2 - 1
d 1 = [e] 1 - d 0 = [g] 1 - 0
d 0 = [f] 0
```

Bad algorithm, bad, bad.

If difference between two numbers is meant:

```
int difference(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a > b)
    {
        return 1 + difference(a - 1, b);
    }
    else //if (a < b)
    {
        return difference(b, a);
    }
}
```

Even if this is home work, a solution:

```
int identityByRecursiveDifference(int a)
{
    return a == 0 ? 0 : 1 + identityByRecursiveDifference(a - 1);
}
```

Here the difference is 1.

```
int identityByRecursiveDifference(int a)
{
    if a == 0 {
        return 0;
    }
    int half = identityByRecursiveDifference(a / 2);
    return 2 * half + (a % 2);
}
```

Here the difference is half; exact with even `a` or about with odd `a`.
`a % 2` is remainder by division of 2.

Less recursion, not *a* steps but ²log *a* steps.

Comment: That's a clear and precise explanation, why the program gives the reported output. +1. Now we need to wait for OP to explain why they expected a different result.

Comment: @CiaPan Assumably the OP's task was to implement the identity function using recursion on with a parameter with a _difference_ to the original parameter. As a -> a-1 is silly, I added a -> a/2 too.

Comment: @CiaPan It must be homework. Any programmer that would do this, one would send to a psychiater.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> difference of numbers

What your program does is calculate the division of the given number by 2 rounded up.

| Input | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 |

If you wish to substract one number from another you need to get 2 numbers from the user which you wish to substract, and use another function.

### After clarification, what you need is to accumulate the subtraction result.
It should look more or less like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int difference(int a);

int difference(int a){

if(a == 0)
    return 0;
return -(a-1) + difference(a-1);
}

int main()

{
    int n;

    printf("Enter number until which you want difference of:\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("The difference of numbers is %d", n + difference(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i mean if i provide 5 the code should run like this 5-4-3-2-1-0 and output should be -5.

Comment: Nice catch, I thought of _differentiate_ or such might be intended, but then again the identity was expected (5 -> 5).